# HTML table alternative rows shading with cellpadding

Tags: html, css

When using `cellpadding="10"` along with alternate row shading, it seems that the backgrounds of the alternative rows don't "expand" with the cellpadding. For example:

[image]

As you can see in the figure above, there are gaps between the background and the extra cellpadding. How do I make the background cover the entire row including the cellpadding?

Here's the HTML style behind it:

`tr:nth-child(even) {background-color: #f2f2f2;}`

Comment: It's been driving me crazy for years, the way people keep saying "alternate" when they really mean "alternative".  But this is the first time I've seen someone say "alternative" when they really mean "alternate".  Congratulations (no sarcasm or criticism intended, I really did enjoy seeing it, in my own perverse way).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They do, but you have to remove `border-spacing` from `table` and then adjust the cellpadding and/or the margins and paddings of the `td` and `th` elements.

By default tables have a spacing between cells, that spacing is not part of the 'content' of the cell but only of the table. Add a border on `table`, `td` and `th` to better understand it. For more information you better look at the [MDN page](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/border-spacing) about border-spacing.

Example without cellpadding:

```css
table {
    border-spacing: 0;
}
td, th {
    padding: 10px 20px;
}
```

Comment: Thanks. For some reason this removed my cellpadding though. Is there any way that I can accomplish the same thing without removing the cellpadding?

Comment: Just remove the `td, th` part, keep only the `table` stuff.

Comment: Doesn't seem to be doing the trick. Keeping `cellspacing="10"` while adding just the `table` css seems to still ignore the spacing between the cells.

Comment: Oh, ok, now I see what's the problem. Change `cellspacing` to `cellpadding`. Not only it's [obsolete](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLTableElement/cellSpacing) but it's also defeating the `border-spacing` CSS. Anyway, it would be best to not use it and keep everything in CSS as it's deprecated on HTML5. So keep your `table` clean and use the CSS I've included in the answer.